# C++11 move constructor was omitted in optimization phase

Tags: c++11, move-constructor

If you run the following C++ codes in both MSVC debug and release configuration. You can get different gCounter result. See below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gCounter = 0;

class Test
{
public:
    Test() 
    {
        printf("constructor\n");
        gCounter++;
    }
    Test( const Test& ) 
    {
        printf("copy constructor\n");
        gCounter++;
    }
    Test( Test&& ) 
    {
        printf("move constructor\n");
        gCounter++;
    }
    Test& operator=( Test& ) 
    {
        printf("assignment\n");
        gCounter++;
    }
    Test& operator=( Test&& ) 
    {
        printf("move assignment\n");
        gCounter++;
    }
    ~Test() {}
};

Test case1()
{
    Test t = Test();
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    case1();
    printf( "%d\n", gCounter );
    return 0;
}
```

Debug Result:

```
constructor
move constructor
2
```

Release Result:

```
constructor
1
```

I am surprise to see the result is different. Is it expected behavior? Does it lead to a big issue, if put some critical logical within move constructor? Is there anyone can help?

Comment: Probably, `case1` function is inlined.

Comment: You probably see the effect of _copy elision_ - which has been an allowed optimzation since C++11 (I think). In C++17 it's mandatory and you should see the same result in the debug build as in the release build if you switch to C++17.